# How to detect backspace key change on text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect any backspace changing on the text input? I have tried both `.change()` and `.keyup()` but these are not doing the job.

**To produce this**:

1- Enter on `i` in the text box (list will filtered)
2- Add another `i` to the text box like `ii` 
3- Remove last `i` with `Backspace` or even Select and Delete. While there is items that contains `i` but nothing showing in the list

```js
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
let val = $(this).val()
if(val==""){
$('.list-group-item').show('slow'); 
}
  $(".list-group-item").each(function(){
    $('.list-group-item:not(:contains('+ val +'))').hide('slow'); 
  });
    setTimeout(function(){ 
     if( $(".list-group-item:visible").length ==0){
        $(".alert-danger").removeClass('d-none');
       }
 }, 1000);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
<ul class="list-group ckeck-div">
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *Remove last i with Backspace or even Select and Delete* <-- Those are two different operations. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to update the result as soon as I change the text box even with Backspace or delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't backspace, it's your `if(val==""){` that is causing the issue. I have modified your code to work and switched your show and hide

```js
$(document).on("input","#filter",function(){
let val = $(this).val();

if(val==""){
alert('Please enter in a search string');
}

$('.list-group-item').hide(); 
    $('.list-group-item:contains('+ val +')').show('slow'); 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
     if( $(".list-group-item:visible").length ==0){
        $(".alert-danger").removeClass('d-none');
       }
 }, 1000);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
<ul class="list-group ckeck-div">
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item animated">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @imvain2 but I need the `if(val==""){}` to send message to user if there is not any match

Comment: @MonaCoder I added the if statement back in. The problem wasn't the actual statement but rather your SHOW statement inside of it.

Comment: There is only on e minor issue here. If a user insert `ii` fast the code still returning back some items (even only contains one `i`)

Comment: @MonaCoder I fixed it. I didn't realize you had redundant code. Your each loop wasn't needed.

Comment: Thanks a lost! imvain2

Answer (score -1):

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/\

```
$('.yourinput').on('input',function(e){
        if(e.which == 8 ) {
          ///do whatever you want to do on the input
        }
```

you could use on keypress also